# WPF with C# How to set item source for a datagrid from background worker result

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

I am learning WPF with C# and trying to make a small application that uses background worker. I am stuck with the worker completed part, with an error stating "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

XAML code block

```
<Window x:Class="DataTable_Return.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="421,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="WMI_grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="192" Width="423"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

and the C# code block as below

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
//using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;


namespace DataTable_Return
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WMI_grid.Items.Clear();

            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(10000);

        }


        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                e.Result = GetTableData();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                e.Result = ex;
            }
        }


        #region "worker_RunWorkerCompleted"
        void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result is DataTable)
            {
                WMI_grid.ItemsSource = e.Result;
            }
            else if (e.Result is Exception)
            {
            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region "worker_ProgressChanged"
        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //pbCalculationProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
        #endregion


        private DataTable GetTableData() {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("HostName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Last Logon", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("OS", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Service Pack", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add("TEST-01", "12-01-2017", "Windows 10 Pro", null);
            dt.Rows.Add("TEST-02", "12-01-2017", "Windows 10 Pro", null);
            dt.Rows.Add("TEST-03", "12-01-2017", "Windows 10 Pro", null);
            dt.Rows.Add("TEST-04", "12-01-2017", "Windows 10 Pro", null);

            return dt;
        }




    //Main grid
    }
   }
```

How do you I address this situation?

Comment: Instead of a DataTable, try converting creating a list of POCO objects and assign them to the ItemsSource

Comment: I'm confident that the question is not a duplicate, as the provided links are not dealing with background worker returned datatables!

Comment: @RajeshThampi Your problem is not related to BackgroundWorker, but just how to get an IEnumerable from a DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code part as follow,

```
 void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result is DataTable)
            {
                WMI_grid.ItemsSource = ((DataTable)e.Result).DefaultView;
            }
            else if (e.Result is Exception)
            {
            }

        }
```

Comment: That solved my situation. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome :-) @RajeshThampi